# What can I use to log into a locked Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I need to access my Gmail account and I don't have the old phone number or the two-step codes to use and I don't have a recovery email or phone number

Comment: This question is not on-topic here whatsoever.  You will need to contact GMAIL or Google support about it.  We cannot help you.  https://support.google.com/mail/?hl=en#topic=7065107